# Azure Devops Server 2020 1.2 patch 8 installation issue

Tags: azure-devops-server-2020

The [documentation listed for Azure Devops Server 1.2 patch 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2020u1?view=azure-devops-2020#azure-devops-server-2020-update-12-patch-10-release-date-november-14-2023) lists the Configure TFX and Update tasks using TFS, but I'm unable to follow those steps for the on premise version of Azure Devops Server. When I click the link for Upload Tasks to the Project Collection, it switches to the documentation for Azure Devops Services, not Azure Devops Server, which makes me think it doesn't apply to Azure Devops Server; especially since I cannot run the command to install tfx-cli. Please clarify which steps are for Azure Devops server and which apply only to Azure Devops Services.

When I clicked on the link to upload tasks to project collection, I need more details on the step to install tfx-cli.  I'm able to install node.js, but the npm command doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is for Azure DevOps Services. However, there is notice that you may use it for the Azure DevOps Server:

[image]

Here you may use that from the document:

```
npm install -g tfx-cli
~$ tfx login
```

then check the instructions on the release page:

```
tfx build tasks upload --task-zip-path AzureFileCopyV1.1.230.0.zip
tfx build tasks upload --task-zip-path AzureFileCopyV2.2.230.0.zip 
tfx build tasks upload --task-zip-path AzureFileCopyV3.3.230.0.zip 
....
....
....
```

Comment: This is the command  (npm install -g tfx-cli) that I'm unable to run.  It cannot be run from within node.js.  Do I run it from the actual on premise server, and do I have to install Node.js on the server or can I run it from my workstation, since I'm the Azure Devops Admin?

Comment: Thanks for answering whether it's for Services or Server.  More specifically, is it a REQUIRED step to apply the patch for Azure Devops Server on premise?

Comment: No it's not required, unless you want to use the newer versions of these tasks. The old versions may not work due to their implementation being deprecated in time cases.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative option through [a PowerShell script that Microsoft Support has shared](https://github.com/jessehouwing/azure-pipelines-tasks-zips/blob/main/scripts/install-task.ps1) in the past. I maintain a [GitHub project that keeps a copy of each released version of a Microsoft task](https://github.com/jessehouwing/azure-pipelines-tasks-zips?tab=readme-ov-file) to enable Azure DevOps Server users to use newer versions of tasks than the ones that ship with the server.

You can download the task-zips from my repository as well. I also offer a version of the taskzip that can be installed side-by-side the official Microsoft ones.

- [Download the taskzips from the same m230 milestone here](https://github.com/jessehouwing/azure-pipelines-tasks-zips/releases/tag/m230-tasks)
- [Download the taskzips from the same m226 milestone here](https://github.com/jessehouwing/azure-pipelines-tasks-zips/releases/tag/m226-tasks)

With the correct zip files from the links above you can install them to your TFS Project collection using:

```
. ./install-task.ps1 -CollectionUrl https://yourtfs.com/tfs/DefaultCollection -TaskZip Task.guid-version.zip
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse.  I'll test this in our development environment.  I appreciate your help.  It appeared that when I ran the patch 8 files on the server, it updated tasks as part of the installation process.  This is what led me to believe that the additional steps were not needed.  Can you confirm or deny?

Comment: I haven't rolled this exact patch anywhere, so I can neither confirm nor deny.